# Can I use google web cache to programatically open a page?

Tags: caching, web-scraping, google-search

I'm using snoopy and phpQuery. If I have a URL, i'd like to open up the cached version of that url on google. Any date, doesn't matter, as long as a version exists i'll take it.

Any ideas on how to do this?

To manually replicate this:

1. Select your url, lets say http://www.abc.net.au/news/infographics/qld-floods/beforeafter.htm
2. Load up http://www.google.com.au
3. Type in this url in the search box
4. The first result is the url, click "Cache" underneath it.

So I want to grab that URL, which looks like this:

http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:BOtHTvfch7UJ:www.abc.net.au/news/infographics/qld-floods/beforeafter.htm+http://www.abc.net.au/news/infographics/qld-floods/beforeafter.htm&cd=1&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=au&source=www.google.com.au

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay just worked it out

http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:http://www.abc.net.au/news/infographics/qld-floods/beforeafter.htm
&hl=en
&strip=1

strip=1 will load the page without css or javascript (I'm guessing it's what the robot sees?).

That's awesome. google rocks.

Comment: google blocks requests from scripts as far as i know. not sure specifically how but i guess since they do it's not supposed to be used like this